# Can I file a child custody claim in French court from abroad?

Tags: france, divorce

I am Pakistani citizen and my husband is living in France as a permanent resident. My husband has taken my children to France without my permission. I need to get custody of my children.

Do I need to visit France to file a case in French court, or is there a way that I can file a case from Pakistan?

Comment: You probably need a lawyer in France.  You probably don't have to go there.  With any luck, someone here will be able to offer some suggestions about finding legal representation.

Comment: Check your department of state for a site like http://travel.state.gov/content/childabduction/en/country/france.html.  Unfortunately, [Pakistan is not a party](http://travel.state.gov/content/childabduction/en/country/pakistan.html) to the Hague Abduction Convention, but France is, and a French lawyer may be able to help you.